# A line of intersection in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, singularity

I have a basic background of calculus 1, and I'm self-teaching linear algebra using Strang's [*Linear Algebra and its Applications,* 3rd ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0155510053) Early on, he describes singular cases, one of which is a 3-dimensional *line of intersection* (drawn myself using Python and PyPlot):

[image: Line of intersection]

Strang explains that "the three planes have a whole line in common" and I can't get an intuition as to what he means by that. I only see the single point of intersection; how is there a line of solutions for these three vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have drawn three lines in the $x,y$ plane with equations
\begin{align}
 y &= 2.5 \cr
 x+y &= 5 \cr
 x-y &= 0 
\end{align}
That intersect in the point $(2.5,2.5)$.

But you can interpret these equations as three planes
in $x,y,z$ space, where it happens that $z$ does not
appear in the equations. That means $z$ may take any
value. Thus the planes intersect along the line
where $(x,y,z) = (2.5,2.5,{\rm any value})$.

Generally in three dimensions an equation of a plane
can be written in the form $ax+by+cz = d$. Strang
is probably giving an examples of what can happen
when you have 3 planes. Often they intersect at
one point, sometimes in a line, sometimes they are
all the same plane, and sometimes they
have no point in common as when two of the planes
are parallel. I didn't describe every case. The idea is to think of all the
geometric possibilities and see how the algebra
relates to each case.